# Zend Framework Controller Mappings

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have my directory structure set up as follows:

```
Application Root
|-application
|  |--configs
|  |--controllers
|  |  |--helpers
|  |
|  |--layouts
|  |  |--scripts
|  |
|  |--models
|  |--views
|     |--scripts
|        |--index
|        |--test
|
|--data
|  |--session
|
|--public
|--index.php
|--.htaccess
```

In my controllers directory, I have 2 controllers: `IndexController` and `TestController` which have identical internal definitions, with 2 methods, `indexAction` and `testingAction`. When I point my browser to `localhost/application` I get the result of my `IndexController.indexAction()` but when I go to `localhost/test` or `localhost/testing` or `localhost/test` or really, any other variation, I get a 404 Not Found error.

I'm using the Zend Framework (1.9.6 I believe), and I've confirmed that there is no issue with the various source PHP files in terms of syntax errors.

Why might I be seeing this behavior and what can I do to fix it?

**EDIT:**

I had another developer send me a full Zend-based application to compare my setup with. There were no apparent differences in terms of the location of files, or the contents of the various configuration files. However, on his site too, I can only access the index page of the site, but none of the internal controllers. He does not have that problem. Is this possibly an issue with my Apache setup?

Comment: What does just `localhost` do in your browser? Is the `public` directory the web root? Not sure how you could end up in the `IndexController` if it isn't, though, unless you put your `index.php` in the `application` directory.

Comment: Entering just localhost/myapp would load the IndexController.indexAction() - but I can't figure out how to get any other action mapped.

Comment: Updated answer, check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check you Apache configs. seems like `.htaccess` `mod_rewrite` does not working properly

UPDATE 1:

also check:

```
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"> # OR WHAT IS IN YOU CONF FILE

   ... SKIP ...
    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
        AllowOverride All

   ... SKIP ...
    </Directory>
```

for `AllowOverride All` option. without it `.htaccess` files does not work

Comment: Would this be located anywhere other than in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: noup. httpd.conf must contain something like LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 1):

1. You should point to localhost/public, not localhost/application.
2. ZF used "index" as default controller and action name. So when you try localhost/public, it will find `localhost/public/index/index`, result to indexController.indexAction. When you pointed to `localhost/test` it will find `localhost/test/index` and `localhost/testing` will result in `localhost/testing/index`.

So, you should try **`localhost/test/testing`**.

Answer (score 0):

You should be pointing your browser to `localhost/public`, which  should contain a `.htacess` file and `index.php`. If you are using the started application as a basis, the `.htaccess` configuration should be setup so that all requests that would have resulted in a 404 end up being passed to `index.php` which then in turn starts the application, loading the appropriate controllers.

**EDIT**
You also have the functions slightly wrong (I think). If you go to `localhost/test` it should call the index action in the test controller (unless you have defined another default action in the configuration).

So if you have a action named test in the test controller, you want to access:

> localhost/public/test/test/

It helps if you set up an error controller, as it makes everything far easier to debug. For example, when I try and access a action that doesn't exist I get this (when in development mode):

> Message: Action "index" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
>
> Stack trace:
>   ...
>
> Request Parameters:
>
> array
>     'controller' => string 'mod' (length=3)
>     'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
>     'module' => string 'default' (length=7)

Comment: But I can get my IndexController.indexAction() to run properly, but nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

u must have `indexAction` in `TestController` to work with url like `localhost/test`

Comment: I do - both Controllers have indexAction and testAction defined